# What is the difference between --impersonate and --service-account-email when using Flex Templates in dataflow?

Tags: dataflow

I'm having a hard time to understand the difference between `--impersonate` and `--service-account-email` when using `gcloud dataflow flex-template run`.

As far as I get it, `--impersonate` is global to `gcloud` whereas the other flag is only for Dataflow related commands.

But in the meantime, I still need to be able to impersonate the Service Account I use when using `--service-account-email`...

So... What is really the difference?

Thanks a lot!
Adrien.

Answer (score 0):

In Dataflow you could think of 3 different identities.

**1. The identity that you are using to communicate with the Dataflow API**

This identity is used when you run "gcloud dataflow jobs run" for instance, or anything else to operate your job.

The call will be made with your user, or by the default service account if you run your command on GCE or GAE for instance. If you run the command as a user, using --impersonate-service-account will run the job as the specified service account instead.

Note that your user needs the "Service Account User" IAM role in order to be able to impersonate a SA. The specified SA could, for instance, have the Dataflow Developer role.

**2. The identity of the Dataflow Service**

This service does things like creating the VMs on GCE that Dataflow needs, or restarting failed jobs. This identity is a service account automatically created by Dataflow.

**3. The identity of the Dataflow Controller**

By default, it is your Compute Engine default service account. You can change it with the --service--account-email parameter.

Make sure your SA has the Dataflow Worker role or the job won't run. Also, this is basically the SA that will be used by your job, so if your job reads from Pub/Sub for instance, it will need appropriate Pub/Sub permissions. (Note that for some IO connectors like BigQueryIO both identity 1 and 3 will need the BigQuery permissions: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#accessing_bigquery_datasets_across_google_cloud_platform_projects).

This SA will appear in the Dataflow UI as "serviceAccountEmail".

Comment: Hello JGO! Thanks for your answer, it helps a lot! It's a shame that the documentation is kinda blurry on that subject, but I'm going to dig in that subject.

Comment: You're welcome. Just realized that it's very close to the way Dataproc identities work but the documentation seems clearer there in terms of separation: end-user identity, control plane identity, data plane identity. https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/iam/dataproc-principals